# Python if modifier precedence

Tags: python

Sorry, I'm sure it was asked a billion times, but I couln't have found exact answer:

```
var = value if condition else other_value
```

What is the precedence of `if .. else` relative to assignment? Like in C/Java ternary or not?

Comment: To clear up why I asked this at all: I'm a python newb, and in some point in my program I suddenly had a suspicion that if `condition` evaluates to `False` then assignment is not executed. Wrong suspicion after all, the bug was in the other place :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The if/else expression is an expression, but assignment is a statement.  So in Python, you don't need to think about precedence of the two, the if/else will be done first.

In C, assignment is also an expression, so you can mix and match the conditional and the assignment in ways you can't in Python.

Answer (score 5):

Assignment always has the lowest precedence; it is not part of the expression.

In fact, assignment is a *statement*; you can never use assignment in an expression.